# PHP How to self declare by parent function in child class?

Tags: php, class, oop, php-7

Parent

```
class MWCEMod {
  private static $mod;

  public function get_mod(){
    var_dump( self );
    if ( null == self::$mod )
        self::$mod = new MWCEMod();
    return self::$mod;
  }
  private function __construct(){
    var_dump('something1');
  }
}
```

Child

```
class MWCEMod_child extends MWCEMod{
  private function __construct(){
    var_dump('something2');
  }
}
add_action( 'MWCE_Load_Mods', array('MWCEMod_acf','get_mod') );
```

I would like to to change above code so `MWCEMod_child::get_mod()` would call `self::$mod = new MWCEMod_child();` not `self::$mod = new MWCEMod();`. Is there any way for doing it?

I'm trying to learn oop PHP on Making Wordpress Plugin. Those are modules for main class and i load them this way:

```
class MonWayContentEditor {

private static $instance;
private $options;

public  $plugin_url,
        $plugin_dir;

public static function get_instance() {
    if( get_current_user_id() == 2 ){
        if ( self::$instance == null )
            self::$instance = new MonWayContentEditor();
        return self::$instance;
    }
    return null;
}
private function __construct(){
    $this->options = array(

    );

    $this->plugin_url = plugins_url().'/monway-editor/';
    $this->plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );

    $this->load_modules();

    do_action( 'MWCE_Load_Mods');
}

private function load_modules(){
    include($this->plugin_dir.'/mods/MWCEMod.php');

    if(class_exists('acf'))
        include($this->plugin_dir.'/mods/acf.php');
}

}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'MonWayContentEditor', 'get_instance' ) );
```

I dont know how to explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing seems to be to create an instance of the derived class as opposed to the base class.  I've altered the code to allow me to show the principle of using [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) and then using this name to create the object.

```
class MWCEMod {
    private static $mod;

    public function get_mod(){
        if ( null == self::$mod )
            $className = get_called_class();
            self::$mod = new $className();
            return self::$mod;
    }
    private function __construct(){
        var_dump('something1');
    }
}

class MWCEMod_child extends MWCEMod{
    public function __construct(){
        var_dump('something2');
    }
}

$n = new MWCEMod_child();
print_r($n->get_mod());
```

This code outputs...

```
.../Test/t1.php:21:
string(10) "something2"
.../Test/t1.php:21:
string(10) "something2"
MWCEMod_child Object
(
)
```